# IP forwarding on windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I want to redirect incoming traffic with a specific IP destination address coming to my computer to proxy server working on this PC (C# app). I tried to accomplish it by using

netsh interface portproxy v4tov4 [specificPort] [specificIP] [somePort] [127.0.0.1]

(I enabled IP routing earlier ofc)

Unfortunately, it's not working ,anyone has any idea why ? Or maybe someone know how to do that in different way ?